# Doubt in chapter $6.8$ of Hoffman and Kunze.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Let $T$ be a linear operator such that minimal polynomial of $T$ is the product of first degree polynomial then $T$ can be written as $D+N$ where $D$ is a diagonalizable linear operator and $N$ is nilpotent linear operator.

Now, this is something that is after the primary decomposition theorem. I am really confused  understand if there is some link between the two.

My understanding is that $T$ w.r.t. some basis can be written as a triangulable linear operator and so it can be written as a sum of nilpotent operator and a diagonalizable linear operator.is this ok?

Comment: If we require that $D$ and $N$ satisfy $DN = ND$, then this decomposition can be seen as a consequence of the existence of Jordan form which is in turn a consequence of primary decomposition. However, the decomposition that you describe does not make any use of the primary decomposition theorem.

Comment: @BenGrossmann can you elaborate this comment as an answer. I am actually not getting it.jordan form has still not been described in the chapter $6$..How are you linking the both?

Comment: Where did you encounter the statement "$T$ can be written as $D + N$ where $D$ is diagonalizable and $N$ is nilpotent"? In this context, is it specified that $DN = ND$? Do you have a reason to believe that this statement is somehow connected to the primary decomposition?

Comment: I don't know. I am not getting the proof or intuition as to why this would happen or why not? I would really appreciate some help

Comment: Please answer the first and second questions that I asked as well

Comment: Yes it is specified. I am trying to understand if there is a link- or we use this theorem of primary decomposition  to prove this statement

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the minimal polynomial of $T$ is the product of first degree polynomials, then $T$ is diagonalizable. This is an immediate consequence of the [Primary Decomposition Theorem](https://www.statlect.com/matrix-algebra/primary-decomposition-theorem).

Therefore

$$T = T + 0$$ where $T$ is diagonalizable and $0$ obviously nilpotent.

Comment: If the minimal polynomial is a product of first degree polynomials **with no repeating factors**, then $T$ is diagonalizable.

Comment: @BenGrossmann For sure!